# Check for app new version in the store

Tags: android

I have the requirement to check for new app versions in the store and if there's one, display a dialog asking user to update the app.

On iOS, this can be nicely accomplished by the official affiliate Search API from Apple. I'm looking for an "official" way of doing the same on Android.

Comment: There is no direct api in android to get new version.
You can accomplish this by using Jsoup to scrape webpage, or using Firebase config or your own API.

Comment: what is "Firebase config"?

Comment: Firebase introduced something called Remote Config, which helps in changing the behavior and appearance of your app without publishing an app update. You can integrate in app, and just need to change value of variable on firebase console on pushing app update.
Link : https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/

Answer (score 1):

This is what i have done in my code

Add the dependency for jsoup

```
  compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.2'
```

and then use this function in an async task to get the version.

```
public String getLatestVersion{
                newVersion = Jsoup.connect("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + Constants.PACKAGE_NAME + "&hl=en")
                        .timeout(3000)
                        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                        .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                        .get()
                        .select("div[itemprop=softwareVersion]")
                        .first()
                        .ownText();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return newVersion;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. But I am looking for an official way.

Comment: There are no as such official way. You can create your own api which you could hit and see if the current version is latest or not

Comment: It would probably be your best bet to use your own API, the way proposed in this answer is really hacky (e.g. if the play store site changes, it would not work anymore)

Comment: Yeah. and in case you don't wanna make your own backend, use firebase storage to refer to the current version and then act accordingly